# Camera forward always remains 0

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-vr

I'm in the process of developing a VR application for Android using unity. The googleVR plugin for unity that I'm using is v1.5 and unity v5.6 
I have a **GvrEditorController** and a camera attached to it.

In order to find the direction I use the code

```
Camera.transform.forward
```

It works as intended in Unity Editor but when it's actually tested in the Android device. **Camera.transform.forward** always returns a **Vector3(0,0,0)**. I have tried googling it but it gave me no results whatsoever. Any guidance will be appreciated.

The GvrEditorController successfully attaches to the camera and changes the view according the the gyroscope but the ***forward*** property remains 0.

Update : Added code

```
void Update () {
    c = Camera.allCameras[0];
    float angle = c.transform.localEulerAngles.x;
    angle = (angle > 180 ? angle - 360 : angle);
    y = transform.localPosition.y;
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        if(angle <80 && angle > -80.0f)
        transform.localPosition += c.transform.forward * 5.0f * Time.deltaTime; //c.transform.forward is (0,0,1) in editor and (0,0,0) on an android device
        transform.localPosition = new Vector3(transform.localPosition.x, y, transform.localPosition.z);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
        if (angle < 80 && angle > -80.0f)
            transform.localPosition -= c.transform.forward * 5.0f * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.localPosition = new Vector3(transform.localPosition.x, y, transform.localPosition.z);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        transform.localPosition -= new Vector3(5.0f,0,0f) *  Time.deltaTime;
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        transform.localPosition += new Vector3(5.0f, 0, 0f) * Time.deltaTime;

    transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYkW1.png) showing the hierarchy of the player. The script shown above is attached to **PlayerCam**

Comment: Show us more code please.

Comment: @mjwills Added code for your reference